# How do I create a custom HTTP error code in Java for an exception?

Tags: java, http, error-handling, error-code

I'm running into the issue of having to differentiate between two error cases which both throw a Java BadrequestException, which shows up as having a 400 error code. I've extended BadrequestException to create a CustomException, but this Exception also throws a 400. Is there a way to have a custom exception throw an "unassigned" error code, like 469, for example? And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: We have no idea of which framework you're using. There are many, many of them. So, find out what you're using, then read the documentation of the framework. It probably contains the information.

Comment: Framework as in angularjs?

Comment: No. AngularJS is a JavaScript framework, used at client-side. You're using a Java framework, at server-side.

Comment: Ohh sorry. We're using Maven.

Comment: Yeah, but that is completely irrelevant. Maven is a build tool. Not a Java web framework. If nobody in your team is able to even name the framework you chose to implement your app, how can you even work? Do you guys never read any documentation?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546848/rest-api-is-it-a-really-bad-practice-to-create-custom-http-response-codes. For your purposes specifically, you should be using an error code in the body instead rather than a new status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using JAX-RS you can create a new exception with a custom HTTP status code like so:

```
public class CustomException extends WebApplicationException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomException() {
        super(469);
    }
}
```